# React Native OneSignal trigger event when opening app from notification

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, notifications, onesignal

I'm building an app in React Native and I'm currently working on the push notifications system using OneSignal.

I have configured my notifications, the related segments and my app so I'm able to receive notifications on the device.

However, I need to execute some code when my app is opened using the notifications. I have configured action buttons (see Android example, picture below) triggering the right code when the app is either open and in focus or open in the background.

[image: Notification example]

I need to achieve the same behavior when my app is fully closed and then opened by the action buttons. Right now, it opens the app on my HomeScreen but doesn't trigger the events.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this, Antoine? I have the exact same question.

Comment: Still not, only thing I know is that on Android, clicking on the ActionButtons open the app (when in background) and trigger the events but not when the app is fully closed and not at all on iOS.

Comment: Dang. I opened an issue on the repository in github, but I haven't received any response. If it's helpful: https://github.com/geektimecoil/react-native-onesignal/issues/332